# can't get input after first time in do while

Tags: c, linux, string

I am trying to fork a child process put him in sleep and wake him up whenever the user enter a line of text to print number of lines entered.

My code is working fine. But weird thing I found is I have to user two gets(str) statement if I didn't the user will be prompted for 1 time only.

if run the code and comment one gets(str) you will know what I mean.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

main () {
    int n;
    char ch;
    pid_t child;
    int erret;
    char str[20];
    int c = 0;

    if ((child = fork ()) < 0) {
        perror ("fork");
        exit (0);
    }

    else {
        //waitpid(child,NULL,0);
        do {
            waitpid (child, NULL, 0);
            printf ("Enter a line(s) \n");
            //funn();
            //fflush(stdin);
            //scanf("%d",&n);
            gets (str);
            gets (str);
            erret = kill (child, SIGCHLD);
            printf ("Signal %d\n", erret);
            if (erret >= 0) {
                c++;
                printf ("You have entered : %d line(s)\n", c);
                //pause();
                //waitpid(child,NULL,0);
            }

            else {
                kill (child, SIGKILL);
                exit (0);

            }
            printf ("\nPress 9 to exit  :");
            fflush (stdin);
            scanf ("%d", &n);
            fflush (stdin);
        } while (n != 9);
        kill (child, SIGKILL);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are certain levels of standards when writing code. More specifically, indentation helps humans read code more efficiently.

Comment: Do not use `gets` it is no longer part of the C standard. Use `fgets` or (better) `getline` (yes it works on `stdin`. **fflush (stdin)** does **NOT** clean the input buffer.

Comment: Furthermore, `gets` is vulnerable to buffer overflows. Hope this isn't part of a networking program accepting arbitrary user input from standard input.

Answer (score 1):

Your concept is flawed, you're forking with out specifying what the parant and child does. So you have a race conditon on `gets`. This is because after the `fork` call two copies of the code is run, one copy by the parent and one copy by the child. So the fix is to add a `swich` or `else if` statement to separate your code into sections for the child and parent.  BTW as already stated use `fgets`

```
switch(fork()):
    case -1:
        //Error
    case 0:
        // Child code
    default:
        // Parant code
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to get repetitive string input as you are trying to do. One of the standard approaches is to gather input until the user signals `EOF` signifying there is no more data to enter. (On Linux `EOF` is generated from the terminal with `ctrl + d`). Without changing your logic and without commenting on your `fork, waitpid, etc..` implementation, the following is one way to handle gathering string input for your program until the users sends an `EOF` by pressing `ctrl+d` on the keyboard:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main () {

    pid_t child;
    int erret;
    int c = 0;

    ssize_t nread = 0;          /* number of chars read by getline  */
    char *lineptr = NULL;       /* string read by (NULL forces getline to allocate) */
    size_t nbytes = 0;          /* number of bytes to read (ignored with lineptr = NULL) */

    if ((child = fork ()) < 0) {
        perror ("fork");
        exit (0);
    }
    else
    {
        waitpid (child, NULL, 0);
        printf ("\nEnter line(s) of text (ctrl+d to exit):\n\n");

        while (printf ("  Input: ") && (nread = getline (&lineptr, &nbytes, stdin) != -1)) 
        {
            erret = kill (child, SIGCHLD);
            printf ("\n  Signal %d\n", erret);

            if (erret >= 0) {
                c++;
                printf ("  You have entered : %d line(s)\n\n", c);
            }
            else
            {
                kill (child, SIGKILL);
                exit (0);
            }
        }

        kill (child, SIGKILL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/ind2

Enter line(s) of text (ctrl+d to exit):

  Input: line one

  Signal 0
  You have entered : 1 line(s)

  Input: line 2

  Signal 0
  You have entered : 2 line(s)

  Input: line 3

  Signal 0
  You have entered : 3 line(s)

  Input: Killed
```