# Using c code to make a caesar cipher?

Tags: c

Hello good people of the stack overflow.

**Explanation**

I am trying to to the following.

My program needs to take a stream of letters as the input and then for the output rotate 13 paces forward.

For example

A becomes N

B becomes O

C becomes P

D becomes Q

and so on

For this program I need to use the ascii table. So for example lower case a=97 once my program is done it becomes n=110

I wrote a little formula for this

c=(c+13-97)% 26+97  where c is my letter. as you can see if c=97 then c will end up being 110.

So here is my program

As it is seen I used an if statment to determine if I have a capital or lower case letter.

```
  /* 97 is lower case a in ascii and 122 is lower case z*/

     # include <stdio.h>

   int main() {

     char c; 

  printf("please enter a character:");


   while (c!=-1) {

    c=getchar();
    putchar (c);

    if ( c>=97 && c<=122) {

    c=(c+13-97)% 26+97 ;
    printf("%c \n " ,c);

      }
     else

      c=(c+13-65) % 26 +65 ;
      printf("%c \n " ,c);


     }
     return 0;
      }
```

My problem is with the output for example if I plug in a

instead of n I get

```
    an
    n

     1
```

Comment: use `{ }` for else block. and replace `else if('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')` also `char c;` --> `int c;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One other issue that you will run into is the need **to flush the \n remaining in the input buffer before reading the next character**. Basically, what occurs is after a character is entered and the user presses `Enter`, `c` is read from the input buffer, but `'\n'` remains. So the next time the loop is entered `\n` is already present in the input buffer and is taken as `c` for that iteration.

To prevent this from occurring, the easiest way to `flush` the input buffer is to declare a throw-away `int` say `int flush` and following each read of a character, add the following:

```
do { flush=getchar(); } while (flush != '\n');
```

This will extract **all** remaining characters from the `input buffer` preparing it for the next read. (**Note:** `fflush` does not do this for input streams) An implementation with this incorporated is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    int c = 0;      /* Always initialize variables */
    int flush = 0;
    int new = 0;

    printf ("\nPlease enter a character (ctrl+d to exit):\n\n");

    while (printf ("  char: ") && (c = getchar()) != -1) {

        do { flush=getchar(); } while (flush != '\n');     /* flush input buffer */

        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        {
            new = (c + 13 - 97) % 26 + 97;
            printf ("\t    lower-case '%c' becomes: '%c'\n\n", c, new);

        } 
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        {
            new = (c + 13 - 65) % 26 + 65;
            printf ("\t    upper-case '%c' becomes: '%c'\n\n", c, new);
        } 
        else 
        {
            printf ("\n    invalid character, try again\n\n");
        }
    }

    printf ("\n\nexiting.\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
Please enter a character (ctrl+d to exit):

char: a
            lower-case 'a' becomes: 'n'

char: b
            lower-case 'b' becomes: 'o'

char: n
            lower-case 'n' becomes: 'a'

char: o
            lower-case 'o' becomes: 'b'

char: A
            upper-case 'A' becomes: 'N'

char: B
            upper-case 'B' becomes: 'O'

char: N
            upper-case 'N' becomes: 'A'

char: O
            upper-case 'O' becomes: 'B'

char:

exiting.
```

Good luck with your project. Drop a comment if you run into additional problems.

---

**Multiple Character Version Using getline**

Regarding your question about line input. Here is a version using `getline` to read multiple characters from `stdin`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    int new = 0;
    ssize_t nread = 0;  /* number of chars read by getline                      */
    char *line = NULL;  /* string holding chars - getline allocates when NULL   */
    size_t n = 0;       /* limit number of bytes to (ignored when 0)            */
    char *p = NULL;     /* point to use to iterate over each char in line       */
    int index = 0;      /* simple index for formatted output.                   */


    printf ("\nPlease enter characters to translate (ctrl+d to exit):\n");

    while (printf ("\n  input: ") && (nread = getline (&line, &n, stdin) != -1)) {

        index = 0;                      /* reset index                  */
        p = line;                       /* assign pointer to line       */
        printf ("\n");                  /* just because it looks nice   */

        while (*p != '\n')              /* getline consumes the '\n'    */
        {

            if (*p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z')
            {
                new = (*p + 13 - 97) % 26 + 97;
                printf ("\t    char[%2d] : %c  =>  %c\n", index, *p, new);

            }
            else if (*p >= 'A' && *p <= 'Z')
            {
                new = (*p + 13 - 65) % 26 + 65;
                printf ("\t    char[%2d] : %c  =>  %c\n", index, *p, new);
            }
            else
            {
                printf ("\n    char[%2d] : %c  =>  invalid character\n", index, *p);
            }

            p++;
            index++;
        }
    }

    printf ("\n\nexiting.\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
Please enter characters to translate (ctrl+d to exit):

  input: aAbBcCmMnNoO

            char[ 0] : a  =>  n
            char[ 1] : A  =>  N
            char[ 2] : b  =>  o
            char[ 3] : B  =>  O
            char[ 4] : c  =>  p
            char[ 5] : C  =>  P
            char[ 6] : m  =>  z
            char[ 7] : M  =>  Z
            char[ 8] : n  =>  a
            char[ 9] : N  =>  A
            char[10] : o  =>  b
            char[11] : O  =>  B

  input:

exiting.
```

Comment: I see yes I noticed that the new character keep messing up with input thanks for pointing out a solution.

Comment: Experience has taught me -- that was the next question coming :)

Comment: Actually I have one more question if you do not mind, it is if I want to input more than one letter say a "abc" and turn it into "nop" would I have to be able to do this using get char and not using a string.

Comment: You can do it with `getchar()` in the same `while` loop. However, I would strongly recommend moving to `getline` and using line oriented input. Look at the `while (printf.. getline..)` command in my answer in [**This Post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372482/cant-get-input-after-first-time-in-do-while/26372862#26372862). Once you get the string from `stdin` it is simply another quick `while (*string)` loop to process each character.

Comment: @humblecomputeruser - I added an example of using line-oriented input with `getline` to my answer -- check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is absolutely fine with some minor changes in it.

```
     /* 97 is lower case a in ascii and 122 is lower case z*/

     # include <stdio.h>

     int main()
     {

     char c;

     printf("please enter a character:");


     while (c!=-1)
     {

       c=getchar();
       //putchar (c);      // Avoid Printing entered character

       if ( c>=97 && c<=122)
       {
          c=((c+13-97)% 26)+97 ;
          printf("%c \n " ,c);
       }
     else
     {                               // Braces missing
          c=((c+13-65) % 26) +65 ;
          printf("%c \n " ,c);
     }
     return 0;
     }
     }
```

Output :

```
please enter a character : a
n
```

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop should be

```
while ((c=getchar()) != EOF)
```

Your code is checking the value of `c` before `c` is initialized. You should have gotten a warning about that.

You should not be using hard-coded ASCII values in your code.  Lower case a is `'a'`. Lower case z is `'z'`.  So, for example, you can write

```
if ( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' )
```

Note that `stdin` buffers characters until you press the `return` key. When you do press the `return` key, `getchar` will give you the character that you typed followed by a newline `'\n'` character.  Your code only handles lower case and upper case characters. You need to modify the code to handle non-alpha characters correctly, e.g. spaces, punctuation, newlines.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to mention that `EOF` is defined as `-1` just to insure no confusion is created in switching the test-clause from `-1` to `EOF`. The problem was checking against the uninitialized `c` as you pointed out, otherwise the test condition was OK.

Comment: Alright I see thanks for the response. I think it should work now.